# Building an expression with maximum value

Tags: algorithm, optimization, f#

Given `n` integers, is there an `O(n)` or `O(n log n)` algorithm that can compute the maximum value of a mathematical expression that can be obtained by inserting the operators `-`, `+`, `*` and parentheses between the given numbers? Assume only binary variants of the operators, so no unary minus, except before the first element if needed.

For example, given `-3 -4 5`, we can build the expression `(-3) * (-4) * 5`, whose value is `60`, and maximum possible.

**Background:**

I stumbled upon this problem some time ago when studying genetic algorithms, and learned that it can be solved pretty simply with a classical genetic algorithm. This runs slowly however, and it's only simple in theory, as the code gets rather ugly in practice (evaluate the expression, check for correct placement of brackets etc.). What's more, we're not guaranteed to find the absolute maximum either.

All these shortcomings of genetic algorithms got me wondering: since we can don't have to worry about division, is there a way to do this efficiently with a more classic approach, such as dynamic programming or a greedy strategy?

**Update:**

Here's an F# program that implements the DP solution proposed by @Keith Randall together with my improvement, which I wrote in a comment to his post. This is very inefficient, but I maintain that it's polynomial and has cubic complexity. It runs in a few seconds for ~50 element arrays. It would probably be faster if written in a fully imperative manner, as a lot of time is probably wasted on building and traversing lists.

```
open System
open System.IO
open System.Collections.Generic

let Solve (arr : int array) =
    let memo = new Dictionary<int * int * int, int>()

    let rec Inner st dr last = 
        if st = dr then 
            arr.[st]
        else
            if memo.ContainsKey(st, dr, last) then
                memo.Item(st, dr, last)
            else
                match last with
                | 0 ->  memo.Add((st, dr, last),
                            [
                                for i in [st .. dr - 1] do
                                    for j in 0 .. 2 do
                                        for k in 0 .. 2 do
                                            yield (Inner st i j) * (Inner (i + 1) dr k)
                            ] |> List.max) 
                        memo.Item(st, dr, last)

                | 1 ->  memo.Add((st, dr, last),
                            [
                                for i in [st .. dr - 1] do
                                    for j in 0 .. 2 do
                                        for k in 0 .. 2 do
                                            yield (Inner st i j) + (Inner (i + 1) dr k)
                            ] |> List.max) 
                        memo.Item(st, dr, last)

                | 2 ->  memo.Add((st, dr, last),
                            [
                                for i in [st .. dr - 1] do
                                    for j in 0 .. 2 do
                                        for k in 0 .. 2 do
                                            yield (Inner st i j) - (Inner (i + 1) dr k)
                            ] |> List.max) 
                        memo.Item(st, dr, last)

    let noFirst = [ for i in 0 .. 2 do yield Inner 0 (arr.Length - 1) i ] |> List.max

    arr.[0] <- -1 * arr.[0]
    memo.Clear()
    let yesFirst = [ for i in 0 .. 2 do yield Inner 0 (arr.Length - 1) i ] |> List.max

    [noFirst; yesFirst] |> List.max

let _ = 
    printfn "%d" <| Solve [|-10; 10; -10|]
    printfn "%d" <| Solve [|2; -2; -1|]
    printfn "%d" <| Solve [|-5; -3; -2; 0; 1; -1; -1; 6|]
    printfn "%d" <| Solve [|-5; -3; -2; 0; 1; -1; -1; 6; -5; -3; -2; 0; 1; -1; -1; 6; -5; -3; -2; 0; 1; -1; -1; 6; -5; -3; -2; 0; 1; -1; -1; 6; -5; -3; -2; 0; 1; -1; -1; 6; -5; -3; -2; 0; 1; -1; -1; 6;|]
```

Results:

> 1000
>   6
>   540
>   2147376354

The last one is most likely an error due to overflow, I'm just trying to show that a relatively big test runs too fast for this to be exponential.

Comment: Initial thoughts - addition / subtraction seems like they'll be rarely used in a solution - multiplication will be the predominant operator used, with + / - used to deal with 1's in the input set (as * 1 is useless!) and to cope with the case where you have an odd number of negative values - where simple multiplication-of-all-values will result in a -ve.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's a proposed solution:

```
def max_result(a_):
  memo = {}
  a = list(a_)
  a.insert(0, 0)
  return min_and_max(a, 0, len(a)-1, memo)[1]

def min_and_max(a, i, j, memo):
  if (i, j) in memo:
    return memo[i, j]
  if i == j:
    return (a[i], a[i])
  min_val = max_val = None
  for k in range(i, j):
    left = min_and_max(a, i, k, memo)
    right = min_and_max(a, k+1, j, memo)
    for op in "*-+":
      for x in left:
        for y in right:
          val = apply(x, y, op)
          if min_val == None or val < min_val: min_val = val
          if max_val == None or val > max_val: max_val = val
  ret = (min_val, max_val)
  memo[i, j] = ret
  return ret

def apply(x, y, op):
  if op == '*': return x*y
  if op == '+': return x+y
  return x-y
```

max_result is the main function, and min_and_max is auxiliary.  The latter returns the minimum and maximum results that can be achieved by sub-sequence a[i..j].

It assumes that maximum and minimum results of sequences are composed by maximum and minimum results of sub-sequences.  Under this assumption, the problem has optimal substructure and can be solved with dynamic programming (or memoization).  Run time is O(n^3).

I haven't proved correctness, but I have verified its output against a brute force solution with thousands of small randomly generated inputs.

It handles the possibility of a leading unary minus by inserting a zero at the beginning of the sequence.

**EDIT**

Been thinking a bit more about this problem, and I believe it can be reduced to a simpler problem in which all values are (strictly) positive and only operators * and + are allowed.

Just remove all zeroes from the sequence and replace negative numbers by their absolute value.

Furthermore, if there are no ones in the resulting sequence, the result is simply the product of all numbers.

After this reduction, the simple dynamic programming algorithm would work.

**EDIT 2**

Based on the previous insights I think I found a linear solution:

```
def reduce(a):
  return filter(lambda x: x > 0, map(abs, a))

def max_result(a):
  b = reduce(a)
  if len(b) == 0: return 0
  return max_result_aux(b)

def max_result_aux(b):
  best = [1] * (len(b) + 1)
  for i in range(len(b)):
    j = i
    sum = 0
    while j >= 0 and i-j <= 2:
      sum += b[j]
      best[i+1] = max(best[i+1], best[j] * sum)
      j -= 1
  return best[len(b)]
```

best[i] is the maximum result that can be achieved by sub-sequence b[0..(i-1)].

**EDIT 3**

Here's an argument in favor of the `O(n)` algorithm based on the following assumption:

You can always achieve the maximum result with an expression of the form

`+/- (a_1 +/- ... +/- a_i) * ... * (a_j +/- ... +/- a_n)`

That is: a product of factors composed of an algebraic sum of terms (including the case of only one factor).

I will also use the following lemmas which are easy to prove:

Lemma 1: `x*y >= x+y` for all `x,y` such that `x,y >= 2`

Lemma 2: `abs(x_1) + ... + abs(x_n) >= abs(x_1 +/- ... +/- x_n)`

Here it goes.

The sign of each factor doesn't matter, since you can always make the product positive by using the leading unary minus.  Hence, to maximize the product we need to maximize the absolute value of each factor.

Setting aside the trivial case in which all numbers are zeroes, in an optimal solution no factor will be composed only of zeroes.  Therefore, since zeroes have no effect inside each sum of terms, and each factor will have at least one non-zero number, we can remove all zeroes.  From now on, let's assume there are no zeroes.

Let's concentrate in each sum of terms separately:

`(x_1 +/- x_2 +/- ... +/- x_n)`

By **Lemma 2**, the maximum absolute value each factor can achieve is the sum of the absolute values of each term.  This can be achieved in the following way:

If x_1 is positive, add all positive terms and subtract all negative terms.  If x_1 is negative, subtract all positive terms and add all negative terms.

This implies that the sign of each term does not matter, we can consider the absolute value of each number and only use operator + inside factors.  From now on, let's consider all numbers are positive.

The crucial step, that leads to an `O(n)` algorithm, is to prove that the maximum result can always be achieved with factors that have at most 3 terms.

Suppose we have a factor of more than 3 terms, by **Lemma 1** we can break it into two smaller factors of 2 or more terms each (hence, each add up to 2 or more), without reducing the total result.  We can break it down repeatedly until no factors of more than 3 terms are left.

That completes the argument.  I still haven't found a complete justification of the initial assumption.  But I tested my code with millions of randomly generated cases and couldn't break it.

Comment: Could you explain the logic behind the linear solution a bit? I also saw Nabb's post and was about to ask him the same thing, but apparently he deleted it. In the meantime I'll try to run some tests myself.

Comment: The key insight is that you'll never need to add groups of more than 3 consecutive numbers.  That's why the inner while loop executes at most 3 times.  And actually, you only need to add groups when there's at least a number one involved.  I'll try to write a longer explanation later.

Comment: @Sheldon - are you accounting for no unary minus? Why are you only working with the absolute value of every number?

Comment: @IVlad: because you can always make the product of groups positive by using the leading unary minus. Hence, you can reduce the problem by considering absolute values and using operators * and + only.

Comment: @Sheldon L. Cooper Never more that 3 numbers ? False ! See 4 1 1 1 1 4
Maximum is 4*4*4 = 64, you need to sum the 1....

Comment: @Loïc - No, it's not necessary: 4 * (1 + 1) * (1 + 1) * 4 = 64.

Comment: @Sheldon L. Cooper Indeed...my mistake.

Answer (score 3):

A reasonable big value can be found in O(N). Consider this a greedy algorithm.

1. Find all positive numbers ≥ 2. Store the result as *A*.
2. Count all "-1"s . Store the result as *B*.
3. Find all negative numbers ≤ -2. Store the result as *C*.
4. Count all "1"s. Store the result as *D*.
5. Initialize *Product* to 1.
6. If *A* is not empty, multiply *Product* by the product of *A*.
7. If *C* is not empty and has even count, multiply *Product* by the product of *C*.
8. If *C* is has odd count, take the smallest number in magnitude of *C* away (store it as *x*), and multiply *Product* by the product of the rest of *C*.
9. If *x* is set and *B* is nonzero, compare *Product × -x* with *Product − x + 1*.

   - If the former is strictly larger, decrease *B* by 1 and multiply *Product* by -*x*, then remove *x*.
   - If the latter is larger, do nothing.
10. Set *Result* to 0. If *Product* ≠ 1, add it to *Result*.
11. Add *D* to *Result*, representing addition of *D* "1"s.
12. Add *B* to *Result*, representing subtraction of *B* "-1"s.
13. If *x* is set, substract *x* from *Result*.

The time complexities are:

1. O(N), 2. O(N), 3. O(N), 4. O(N), 5. O(1), 6. O(N), 7. O(N), 8. O(N), 9. O(1), 10. O(1), 11. O(1), 12. O(1), 13. O(1),

so the whole algorithm runs in O(N) time.

---

An example session:

```
-3 -4 5
```

1. *A* = [5]
2. *B* = 0
3. *C* = [-3, -4]
4. *D* = 1
5. *Product* = 1
6. *A* is not empty, so *Product* = 5.
7. *C* is even, so *Product* = 5 × -3 × -4 = 60
8. -
9. -
10. *Product* ≠ 1, so *Result* = 60.
11. -
12. -
13. -

> 5 × -3 × -4 = 60

```
-5 -3 -2 0 1 -1 -1 6
```

1. *A* = [6]
2. *B* = 2
3. *C* = [-5, -3, -2]
4. *D* = 1
5. *Product* = 1
6. *A* is not empty, so *Product* = 6
7. -
8. *C* is odd, so *x* = -2, and *Product* = 6 × -5 × -3 = 90.
9. *x* is set and *B* is nonzero. Compare *Product × -x* = 180 and *Product − x + 1* = 93. Since the former is larger, we reset *B* to 1, *Product* to 180 and remove *x*.
10. *Result* = 180.
11. *Result* = 180 + 1 = 181
12. *Result* = 181 + 1 = 182
13. -

> 6 × -5 × -3 × -2 × -1 + 1 − (-1) + 0 = 182

```
2 -2 -1
```

1. *A* = [2]
2. *B* = 1
3. *C* = [-2]
4. *D* = 0
5. *Product* = 1
6. *Product* = 2
7. -
8. *x* = -2, *Product* is unchanged.
9. *B* is nonzero. Compare *Product × -x* = 4 and *Product − x + 1* = 5. Since the latter is larger, we do nothing.
10. *Result* = 2
11. -
12. *Result* = 2 + 1 = 3
13. *Result* = 3 − (-2) = 5.

> 2 − (-1) − (-2) = 5.

Comment: +1, that's pretty nice. Your last two examples also serve as counterexamples however. We can get `6` for the last: `-2 * (-2 + (-1))`. Also, for `-5 -3 -2 0 1 -1 -1 6` we can do `-5 * (-3 + -2 + 0 - 1 + -1 + -1) * 6 = -30 * -8 = 240`.

Comment: @IVlad: Ha right. The addition/subtraction of ±1s should be done on the largest integer instead of the final product. I'll try to improve the algorithm tomorrow.

Comment: Apparently we can get `540` for the second example. It works by multiplying the first three numbers, adding up all those until the `6` and multiplying with the first 3, then multiplying with the `6`.

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to do this with dynamic programming.  Let `x_i` be your input numbers.  Then let `M(a,b)` be the maximum value you can get with the subsequence `x_a` through `x_b`.  You can then compute:

```
M(a,a) = x_a
M(a,b) = max_i(max(M(a,i)*M(i+1,b), M(a,i)+M(i+1,b), M(a,i)-M(i+1,b))
```

edit:

I think you need to compute both the max and min computable value using each subsequence.  So

```
Max(a,a) = Min(a,a) = x_a
Max(a,b) = max_i(max(Max(a,i)*Max(i+1,b),
                     Max(a,i)*Min(i+1,b),
                     Min(a,i)*Max(i+1,b),
                     Min(a,i)*Min(i+1,b),
                     Max(a,i)+Max(i+1,b),
                     Max(a,i)-Min(i+1,b))
...similarly for Min(a,b)...
```

Comment: In fact this is cubic.  Sorry, I missed your required time bound.

Comment: I don't think this works, since the problem doesn't have optimal substructure.  Consider the input [-10, 10, -10], the maximum is 1000, but it doesn't come from maximums of subsequences.

Comment: Actually guys that's `O(3^n)`, not `O(n^3)`. Since you have `n - 1` variables and 3 values for every variable, you have `n^3 - 1` possible solutions and this approach checks every single one of them.

Comment: @Sheldon - true, but it should be fixable by adding a third dimension : `M(a,b,c) = maximum value obtainable with the subsequence x_a through x_b, and the last operation is c`. @Dave - this would be implemented in the same way as the optimal matrix multiplication. It's cubic. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_chain_multiplication - although I'll concede that I'm no longer 100% sure of its correctness. I still think there's a polynomial solution though.

Comment: Ok, matrix chain multiplication is different because the answer space is polynomial. In this algorithm, the answer space is exponential. The point of dynamic programming is to pre-compute sub-problems to avoid unnecessary recursion. That doesn't help though if you have exponentially many sub-problems.

Comment: @Dave - the way the algorithm is written, it will be cubic. Whether or not it will give the correct answer all the time, I'm not sure. I think that if we add a third dimension like I explained in my last comment, it will work. How do you know the answer space here is exponential and there's no approach (maybe other than the one this solution uses) that avoids unnecessary recursion?

Comment: The answer space is exponential because there are `n^(3-1)` possible answers. I'm saying you ARE avoiding unnecessary recursion, but it won't help because you're setting out to compute exponentially many answers and compare them all. Here's a small example to hopefully help your intuition. With 3 matrices A, B, and C, there are 2 possible answers. (A * B) * C and A * (B * C). With 3 numbers [a, b, c], there are 9 possible answers. a + b + c, a + b - c, a + b * c, and so on. Try it for 4 matrices and 4 numbers, see how they grow.

Comment: The number of ways n factors can be completely parenthesized is also exponential.  More precisely it's C_{n-1}, where C is the sequence of Catalan numbers: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catalan_number#Applications_in_combinatorics

Comment: @Dave - okay, but that is an informal argument. Also informally, I have posted an implementation of this method that, in my opinion, runs too fast for big tests to be exponential. @Sheldon - that doesn't mean anything by itself. Basically, you have to prove that you actually need to check ALL possibilities to get the optimum.

Comment: @IVlad: I was responding to Dave's claim that the number of ways to parenthesize matrices does not grow exponentially.  That's false.

Comment: @IVlad: the algorithm you proposed is obviously polynomial, since the number of subproblems is 3*n*(n+1)/2.  But I'm not convinced about its correctness.

Comment: @Sheldon - I am not entirely convinced myself. Hopefully more people will share their expertise.

Comment: @IVlad: I think your algorithm will break with input [0, 1, 2, -2].  The answer is ((0 - (1 + 2)) * (-2)) = 6, but your algorithm will respond 5.

Comment: @Sheldon, you're right, this doesn't work with [-10,10,-10].  I think you might be able to fix it by computing both the max and min of subsequences.  And it is definitely cubic, you need to compute O(n^2) M values and each one takes O(n) time.  You can order them to avoid any repeat calculation, for instance do the M(a,b) in order from smallest b-a to largest b-a.

Comment: @Keith: Yes, that's what I implemented in my answer.

Comment: @Sheldon, I stand corrected about the growth in the ways you can parenthesize matrices. Good catch.

Answer (score 1):

Work this in reverse polish - that way you don't have to deal with parentheses.  Next put a - in front of every -ve number (thereby making it positive).  Finally multiply them all together.  Not sure about the complexity, probably about `O(N)`.

EDIT: forgot about 0.  If it occurs in your input set, add it to the result.

Comment: watch out for numbers that `|x| < 2` though. They need to be added not multiplied.

Comment: @Kenny -- I was just editing the question while you were pointing out my mistake.  Thanks.

Comment: I'd _hope_ that the problems disallows placing a - in front of every negative value - otherwise it becomes a trivial problem, not that it seems that complex from the outset.

Comment: I can see reverse polish helping in a genetic algorithm approach, but I don't see how it would help in a deterministic approach. Also, you wouldn't multiply a string of all 1s, so multiplying them all after they're positive isn't going to work.

Comment: @Will A - true. Let's assume no unary minus, except for the first element. I'll edit this in.

Answer (score 0):

This feels NP Complete to me, though I haven't yet figured out how to do a reduction. If I'm right, then I could say

- Nobody in the world knows if any polynomial algorithm exists, let alone `O(n log n)`, but most computer scientists suspect there isn't.
- There are poly time algorithms to estimate the answer, such as the genetic algorithm you describe.
- In fact, I think the question you mean to ask is, "Is there a reasonably useful `O(n)` or `O(n log n)` algorithm to estimate the maximum value?"

Comment: No offense or anything, I know you're trying to help, but how can you say that when @Keith Randall posted a polynomial solution just a while ago? Polynomial algorithms that give exact answers definitely exist for this problem, I'm just looking for something efficient.

Comment: Hey @IVlad, I believe your runtime analysis of @Keith's solution is incorrect. It's exponential, not polynomial. Check my logic in his comments and see if I've made a mistake.

Answer (score 0):

This is my first post on stackoverflow, so I apologize in advance for missing any preliminary etiquette. Also, in the interest of full disclosure, Dave brought this problem to my attention.

Here's an `O(N^2logN)` solution, mostly because of the the repeated sorting step in the for loop.

1. **Absolute values:** Remove zero elements and sort by absolute value. Since you are allowed to place a negative sign in front of your final result, it does not matter whether your answer is negative or positive. Only the absolute values of all numbers in the set matter.
2. **Multiplication only for numbers > 1:** We make the observation that for any set of positive integers greater than 1, (e.g. `{2,3,4}`), the largest result comes from a multiplication. This can be shown by an enumerative technique or a contradiction argument over permitted operations + and -. e.g. `(2+3)*4 = 2*4 + 3*4 < 3*4 + 3*4 = 2*(3*4)`. In other words, multiplication is the most "powerful" operation (except for the 1s).
3. **Addition of the 1s to the smallest non-1 numbers:** For the 1s, since multiplication is a useless operation, we are better off adding. Here again we show a complete ordering on the result of an addition. For rhetoric sake, consider again the set `{2,3,4}`. We note that: `2*3*(4+1) <= 2*(3+1)*4 <= (2+1)*3*4`. In other words, we get the most "mileage" from a 1 by adding it to the smallest existing non-1 element in the set. Given a sorted set, this can be done in `O(N^2logN)`.

Here's what the pseudo-code looks like:

```
S = input set of integers;

S.absolute();
S.sort();

//delete all the 0 elements
S.removeZeros();

//remove all 1 elements from the sorted list, and store them
ones = S.removeOnes();

//now S contains only integers > 1, in ascending order S[0] ... S[end]
for each 1 in ones:
   S[0] = S[0] + 1; 
   S.sort();
end

max_result = Product(S);
```

Answer (score 0):

I know I'm late to the party, but I took this on as a challenge to myself.  Here is the solution I came up with.

```
type Operation =
    | Add
    | Sub
    | Mult

type 'a Expr =
    | Op of 'a Expr * Operation * 'a Expr
    | Value of 'a

let rec eval = function
    | Op (a, Add, b)  -> (eval a) + (eval b)
    | Op (a, Sub, b)  -> (eval a) - (eval b)
    | Op (a, Mult, b) -> (eval a) * (eval b)
    | Value x -> x

let rec toString : int Expr -> string = function
    | Op (a, Add, b)  -> (toString a) + " + " + (toString b)
    | Op (a, Sub, b)  -> (toString a) + " - " + (toString b)
    | Op (a, Mult, b) -> (toString a) + " * " + (toString b)
    | Value x -> string x

let appendExpr (a:'a Expr) (o:Operation) (v:'a) =
    match o, a with
    | Mult, Op(x, o2, y) -> Op(x, o2, Op(y, o, Value v))
    | _                  -> Op(a, o, Value v)

let genExprs (xs:'a list) : 'a Expr seq =
    let rec permute xs e =
        match xs with
        | x::xs ->
            [Add; Sub; Mult]
            |> Seq.map (fun o -> appendExpr e o x)
            |> Seq.map (permute xs)
            |> Seq.concat
        | [] -> seq [e]
    match xs with
    | x::xs -> permute xs (Value x)
    | [] -> Seq.empty

let findBest xs =
    let best,result =
        genExprs xs
        |> Seq.map (fun e -> e,eval e)
        |> Seq.maxBy snd
    toString best + " = " + string result
```

`findBest [-3; -4; 5]`
returns `"-3 * -4 * 5 = 60"`

`findBest [0; 10; -4; 0; 52; -2; -40]`
returns `"0 - 10 * -4 + 0 + 52 * -2 * -40 = 4200"`

It should work with any type supporting comparison and the basic mathmatical operators, but FSI will constrain it to ints.